# ElasticSearch analyzed and not_analyzed at the same time

Tags: elasticsearch

My documents for ElasticSearch are of the form:

```
{
    "message": "Message text",
    "user_email": "user@email.net"
}
```

There are two types of queries executed against these documents:

1. Human queries over '_all' fields that should match both 'message' and 'user_email' using analyzers.
2. Machine queries that should use exact match 'user_email'.

Is there a way to create both 'analyzed' and 'not_analyzed' indexes for a single field in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to the above problem is to define two different fields corresponding to user_email, i.e., "user_email_analyzed" and "user_email_not_analyzed" when creating the index. Afterwards, during the indexing phase, you should update the context on both email fields.

Comment: I count on a less hackish solution, especially one that does not require client-side changes.

Comment: Having the email field analyzed, you can achieve the above functionality on query.

Do a 

"{ "query" : { "match" : { "user_email" : "email_to_be_searched"}}}"

for an exact email match.

For the human queries use the query that you currently have. Unfortunately, you will have to do client-side changes in this case :-(